# Massive storage on android devices

Tags: android, cordova, mobile

I am using Icenium to build an application using map services, localisation services and more. I just realised that android-devices stores massive ammounts of pictures in the phones image-gallery. The application is build to look good on any device, therefore, all icons (and some images) come in 4 different sizes (high definition, low definition etc).

So when I start the application on a android-device, the image gallery instantly gets ALL the images that can be used with the app (around 600 small icons + some images).

This is a huge problem, and I havent really found a way to solve this. Is it a built in "feature" of icenium or is it a bug?

edit* Images/icons are fetched from a server at launch, so we do not want them to store locally..

Thanks!
//Joakim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Icenium guys (check out this forum http://www.icenium.com/resources/forums/android-devices-/app-icons-and-images-displayed-in-gallery#a8qHkcQkbkiGelukQjTr6g), this is only true when your application is build in Debug, because in this case your app is on the SD card. Once the application is built in Release you should not see the app images in the gallery as it would be sandboxed (not on SD).